# Unable to access methods in dll generated from WSDL using SVCUtil

Tags: vba, vb.net, dll, wsdl, svcutil.exe

I am attempting to create a dll from a WSDL file for accessing a web service within a VBA application. When using the compiled library I can't call the class methods i need, only the methods with similar names which are built in the proxy to build the main request/response.

This is the procedure I have tried:

- Generate proxy classes in vb.net using svcutil.exe
- Compile proxy classes to dll library using vbc.exe
- Register dll using regasm.exe
- Add reference to tlb file from within VBA (Excel)
- call method from within VBA after defining an instance of the class

Svcutil "https://deltek.XXXXXX.com/Vision/visionws.asmx?wsdl" /language:vb /syncOnly

vbc /t:library /out:DeltekVisionOpenAPIWebService.dll DeltekVisionOpenAPIWebService.vb

regasm /codebase /tlb DeltekVisionOpenAPIWebService.dll

An extract of the generated vb file:

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit On



<System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0"),  _
 System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute([Namespace]:="http://tempuri.org/Deltek.Vision.WebServiceAPI.Server/DeltekVisionOpenAPIWebServi"& _ 
    "ce", ConfigurationName:="DeltekVisionOpenAPIWebServiceSoap")>  _
Public Interface DeltekVisionOpenAPIWebServiceSoap

'CODEGEN: Generating message contract since element name ConnInfoXML from namespace http://tempuri.org/Deltek.Vision.WebServiceAPI.Server/DeltekVisionOpenAPIWebService is not marked nillable
    <System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action:="http://tempuri.org/Deltek.Vision.WebServiceAPI.Server/DeltekVisionOpenAPIWebServi"& _ 
        "ce/UpdateOpportunity", ReplyAction:="*")>  _
    Function UpdateOpportunity(ByVal request As UpdateOpportunityRequest) As UpdateOpportunityResponse

End Interface

Partial Public Class DeltekVisionOpenAPIWebServiceSoapClient
    Inherits System.ServiceModel.ClientBase(Of DeltekVisionOpenAPIWebServiceSoap)
    Implements DeltekVisionOpenAPIWebServiceSoap

    <System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)>  _
    Function DeltekVisionOpenAPIWebServiceSoap_UpdateOpportunity(ByVal request As UpdateOpportunityRequest) As UpdateOpportunityResponse Implements DeltekVisionOpenAPIWebServiceSoap.UpdateOpportunity
        Return MyBase.Channel.UpdateOpportunity(request)
    End Function

    Public Function UpdateOpportunity(ByVal ConnInfoXML As String, ByVal DataXML As String) As String
        Dim inValue As UpdateOpportunityRequest = New UpdateOpportunityRequest()
        inValue.Body = New UpdateOpportunityRequestBody()
        inValue.Body.ConnInfoXML = ConnInfoXML
        inValue.Body.DataXML = DataXML
        Dim retVal As UpdateOpportunityResponse = CType(Me,DeltekVisionOpenAPIWebServiceSoap).UpdateOpportunity(inValue)
        Return retVal.Body.UpdateOpportunityResult
    End Function

End Class
```

I expect to be able to call the class methods that relate to the web service calls, but the only methods that are available (returned by autocomplete/don't error as not defined when called) are the methods used to build the request and response as defined in the interface.

[image: VBA method error]

Edit:
Somehow missed that regasm was reporting this error, but not sure how to address it:

Type library exporter warning processing 'DeltekWebAPI.DeltekVisionOpenAPIWebServiceSoapClient, DeltekVisionOpenAPIWebService'. Warning: Type library exporter encountered a type that derives from a generic class and is not marked as [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]. Class interfaces cannot be exposed for such types. Consider marking the type with [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)] and exposing an explicit interface as the default interface to COM using the ComDefaultInterface attribute.

Comment: ...the COM type you're generating adheres to and implements the interface you're telling it - *that is your public API*. If you need that API to be different, define it differently.

Comment: Thanks @MathieuGuindon. What I don't understand is why the public function defined in the class is not available (Will only methods defined in the interface be exposed?) And, if that is the case why is the tool generating the code this way?

Comment: Missed I was getting a (probably helpful!) error from regasm. Added above.